# Can anybody recommend a good source for material of Gaussian and Complex Gaussian wavelet?

Tags: wavelet, reference-request

Can anybody recommend a good source for material of Gaussian and Complex Gaussian wavelet?
Please share the link if possible.

Comment: Welcome to SE.DSP. Some of us are able to do so, yet could you tell us more about why you need it, and what you have found so far?

Comment: I need to prepare a presentation on these two wavelets to present in front of class.And it is also included in my syllabus so I have to study them for my end term exams. 
 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242806993_Gaussian_wavelet_features_and_their_applications_for_analysis_of_discretized_signals                           I have found only this much and nothing on complex gaussian wavelet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notion of "Gaussian wavelet", whether real or complex, is not clear from the literature. Indeed, the Gaussian has a positive average, while wavelets are (or should be) zero-mean (to satisfy the admissibility condition).

Two standard wavelets may suit your need:

- [the Morlet wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morlet_wavelet), or [Gabor wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_wavelet), a complex exponential  multiplied by a Gaussian window envelope (or its real part),
- derivatives of Gaussians (including  d[ifferences of Gaussians or DoG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians)), sometimes called Ricker wavelet in 1D in geosciences or [mexican hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_hat_wavelet) in 2D.

Their complex extensions, or real restrictions, are relatively natural.

Comment: another generalization of Morlet is the [chirplet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirplet_transform).  not calling it that, i essentially use that in this [paper regarding time-scaling in a modified phase vocoder](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3927319_Intraframe_time-scaling_of_nonstationary_sinusoids_within_the_phase_vocoder/).

Comment: Indeed, and I am glad for the flattened Hann window I haven't met before